# confusion with kubernetes high level architecture (master and node components)

Tags: kubernetes

The [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/) describes the two types of components that live within a kubernetes cluster: master components and node components. I wasn't able to find diagrams that accurately and completely described the components as described in the docs. The [only official diagram](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/design/architecture.md) I found hasn't been updated for 1.5 years.

Personally, I find diagrams a very useful resource to understand concepts. Therefore, I created my own diagrams and would like to know, if I'm missing anything.

Thank you.

**Kubernetes High-Level Architecture**
[image: Kubernetes High-Level Architecture]

**Kubernetes Master Component**
[image: Kubernetes Master Component]

**Kubernetes Node Component**
[image: Kubernetes Node Component]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advices:

- There could be any number of master nodes, so I would make this visible somehow on the diagram.
- kube-proxy and kubelet runs on every node, even on master nodes.
- docker can be interchanged with rkt as well, I would show it up as well.
- fluentd is not part of the core architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What's the relation between `kube-proxy` & `kubelet` with the other components within the master component? Also, I'm not sure if I understood the concept behind `kube-proxy` - basically, it manages all the SDN things, right?

Comment: Actually kube-proxy is not doing anything with the kubelet, and vica-versa. They just happen to be always coupled together because of the architectural decisions. kube-proxy watches the API server for changes in the services and pods definitions, and puts down the correct iptables rules on the actual node to make the VIP (virtual IP) based communication work between the pods and the services on that node.